# How DispatchQueue.main.sync works

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, dispatch-queue

Why does this code crash the app if done on the main queue?

```
 DispatchQueue.main.sync
 {
     NSLog("Start again")
 }
```

Whereas, if done on any other queue, it works.

```
private let internalQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "RealmDBInternalQueue")
```

```
internalQueue.async
 {
    DispatchQueue.main.sync
    {
        NSLog("Start again")
    }
 }
```

I wanted to know how exactly these instructions were passed to Main from the internal queue and how the internal queue gets to know when work is done.

Comment: [Calling this function and targeting the current queue results in deadlock.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1452870-sync)

Comment: `Deadlock` is the keyword term you are missing for your research ;)